# How can I use a calculated field in another calculation further down in the query?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If I have a table that has a few native fields, such as: monthly written premium. But I used that field in combination with some date logic to calculate and create fields in the query called: CY YTD Written premium; PY YTD Written premium; and PY Written Premium.

**How can I use those created fields in another calculation further down in the query.**

What I need to do is take YTD Written Premium - PY YTD Written Premium + CY YTD Written Premium to create LTM Written Premium.

Snowflake will not allow me to reference the 3 fields needed to make LTM because they are not native to the table.

I know it has to be some sort of embedded query, but I'm unsure on the syntax.

Comment: Did you try with the WITH clause , where you calculate the column in the WITH clause and then use those by joining with the original table. Check the following link for an example.  https://dwgeek.com/snowflake-reuse-computed-column-derived-columns.html/

Comment: Maybe this is the answer to your question [stackoverflow.com/questions/73792160](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73792160/how-to-join-two-tables-based-on-a-calculated-field/73792285#73792285)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snowflake supports inline column lateral reference, thus referencing alias at the same SELECT level will work as long as there is no nesting of windowed functions or shadowing table columns:

```
SELECT 
   expr AS col1,
   expr2 AS col2,
   col1 + col2 AS col3
FROM table;
```

Sample (col1, col2, col3 are expressions):

[image]